# Cannot iterate through a dictionary, how to check if it`s empty?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I am trying to upgrade a server for a web application, I have to iterate through a key value dictionary, but I am given the following error

`FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'ansible.utils.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'iteritems'"}`

I tried

```
    {  
      "version":"{{ version.actual_version_number }}",  
      "integrations": {  
    {% for id, port in integration_details.items() %}  
      {% if integration_details is defined and integration_details is not empty %}  
        {{ id }} : {{ port }}  
      {% endif %}  
      {%- if not loop.last -%},{% endif %}  
    {% endfor %}  
      }  
    }
```

If anyone could help with this problem would be really appreciated!

Comment: How does you data structure look like?

Comment: How are you defining `integration_details`? Can you provide the playbook you're running?

Comment: [I downvoted because without code, it is very hard to help you](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/). Follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that your data structure is a dict use `if integration_details is defined and integration_details.keys()|length > 0` this will check if there are any subkeys present. If its a list use `if integration_details is defined and integration_details|length > 0`

But seeing the error you posted you might have a for loop with `iteritems()`somewhere, which is not in the code you posted.

This may be because you use python3 but want to iterate your dict with iteritems() instead of items() or your variable is not a dict but a different type.

Comment: May not apply for this use case, but in a loop one can simply allow the loop to run (or use something like `| default([])` ). If the list is empty nothing will happen.